# Export-world only exports the first 22 turtle-own variables in Netlogo 6.2

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying out export-world in Netlogo 6.2. It seems to work fine and completes exporting all types of things ending with EXTENSIONS-- but in the TURTLES section of the exported file all of the variable values after first 20 or so are null.  When I reimport it it does in fact set all those turtle-owned variables to null. Any idea why ?

Wade

Comment: Do you have a minimal case you can post to reproduce?  I setup a simple model with 30 `turtles-own` variables, filled them with random data, and exported and the file contains info for all the variables.

Comment: yes, working on stripping down to something small and postable.